# Delete from one table with lookup on another table

Tags: mysql

As part of a pruning process, I am trying to delete data from a table which is not used anymore. There are search jobs (table Search) which have results (table Res), and people receive the search results (table Abo) via email. For every Abonnement, the last result sent via email is saved in the column "last_result".

What I want to do: For every search job, I want to delete all results which have been sent to the users.

This is a simplified variant of the structure:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5ef8a3

```
Abo
---

user   search    last_result
A      1         100
B      1         200
C      2         50
D      3         100

Res
---

id     search
50      1           <---- this should be deleted
300     1
51      2

Search
------

1
2
3
```

What I tried to do is something like this:

```
DELETE r
FROM Res r
JOIN Abo a ON r.search = a.search
WHERE
    r.id < min(a.last_res)
```

For every "search" value, I want to delete all results ("Res") which are below the "last_res" field in the "Abo" table.

Comment: There are no rows in the two tables where `r.search = a.search`. Are you sure those are the fields to join on?

Comment: I accidently swapped the columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group `MIN(last_res)` by `search`, so the way to do this is to write a subquery that calculates this, then join with that subquery.

```
DELETE r
FROM Res AS r
JOIN (SELECT search, MIN(last_res) AS min_res
      FROM Abo
      GROUP BY search) AS a
ON r.search = a.search AND r.id < a.min_res
```